# How to prevent SaveAs dialog in Word in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, ribbonx

I am developing a custom ribbon in Microsoft Word document. I intend to override the save functionality by disabling it and save the document programmatically.

I have added `DocumentBeforeSave` event Handler to save the document. Here is the part of the code to save the document

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DocumentBeforeSave += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler(this.Application_DocumentBeforeSave);
}

public void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document document, ref bool saveAsUI, ref bool cancel)            
{
    String destFolder = @"D:\report\tempFolder\";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String fileName = "Temp_" + rnd.Next(1000, 9999).ToString() + ".docx";
    var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destFolder, fileName);

    document.SaveAs2(destFile);
}
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Dunno, never done add-ins for Word/Office. But did you notice that one parameter of the event handler named "saveAsUI"? Would you think that name is a coincidence? I tend to believe not...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, Thanks. I did set saveasUI as False, however, when i try to save it does not prompt the save as dialog and does not close the word document as well.

Comment: Doesn't calling document.SaveAs2 trigger this event? This looks somewhat like a recursion to me with presumably weird behavior then.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, you are trying to save the document by calling the `SaveAs2` method in the `DocumentBeforeSave` event handler. Calling the `SaveAs2` method triggers the `DocumentBeforeSave` method, so you will get a recursion and your dialog will never be displayed.

> How to prevent SaveAs dialog in Word in C#?

In the `DocumentBeforeSave` event handler you may set up the `saveAsUI` parameter which is true if the `Save As` dialog box is displayed, whether to save a new document, in response to the `Save` command; or in response to the `Save As` command; or in response to the `SaveAs` or `SaveAs2` method.